# xsl add element at top

Tags: xml, xslt

Newbie here. I have an XML file populated with data like this:

```
<marker>
        <name>CIP-67</name>
        <address>Husterhohe</address>
        <country>DE</country>
</marker>
```

I want to add this element:

```
<id>9999</id>
```

above the name element so it looks like this:

```
<marker>
        <id>9999</id>
        <name>CIP-67</name>
        <address>Husterhohe</address>
        <country>DE</country>
</marker>
```

My XSL file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <id>9999</id>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This, of course, places the new element below the name element. How do I place it above the name element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should think about the insertion primarily in the context primarily of the insertion's parent, not its sibling. Try this (which includes some other alterations for streamlining):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="marker">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <id>9999</id>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more simple way to do it in XSLT 1.0

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
<marker>
<id>9999</id>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="marker/*"/>
</marker>   
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="marker/*">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```